# adobe flex how to remove space between BOX, VBOX, HBOX

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript

```
<mx:VBox horizontalGap="0" verticalGap="0" height="84" width="164" verticalAlign="middle" styleName="amount">
    <s:Label text="text" width="100%" textAlign="center"/>
    <s:Label text="text" width="100%" textAlign="center"/>
</mx:VBox>
<mx:Box width="1" height="84" borderStyle="solid">

</mx:Box>
<mx:VBox horizontalGap="0" verticalGap="0" height="84" width="144" verticalAlign="middle" styleName="amount">
    <s:Label text="text" width="100%" textAlign="center"/>
    <s:Label text="text" width="100%" textAlign="center"/>
</mx:VBox>
```

I've tried to use horizontalGap and the VerticalGap setted to 0, but that doesn't work, how to remove the gap between mx boxes?

Comment: Maybe try setting the margins to 0 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "gap" properties specify how much of a gap should be applied when laying out the Box's children.

For example, your code below where the gap properties are 0, means that this `VBox` should layout it's child elements (the labels) with no vertical gap (the horizontal gap in this case is useless, since we're talking about a `VBox`).

```
<mx:VBox horizontalGap="0" verticalGap="0" height="84" width="164" verticalAlign="middle" styleName="amount">
    <s:Label text="text" width="100%" textAlign="center"/>
    <s:Label text="text" width="100%" textAlign="center"/>
</mx:VBox>
```

So what is the container that contains all of your boxes above? If that container is a `VBox`, set the `verticalGap` of that parent container object to 0. If it's an `HBox`, set it's `horizontalGap` to 0.